# Performance issue when adding more than 1k routes on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to add 1k routes to Android phone but I found it will take a really long time to add them which is a terrible user experience.

I tried my best to reduce number of routes but 1k is already the best I can get.

I am wondering if there is any other way around to get better performance?

Comment: Can you give us more info about how you're adding those routes?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have set up a VPN server and I want to automatically bypass VPN server when users accessing local website, so I used following:
route 14.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 27.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 36.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 39.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 42.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 net_gateway

Unfortunately I have about 1,000 routes to add and it will take several minutes to finish, I am wondering what should I do to fine-tune the performance? Or we have better way to do it.

Comment: Can anyone help please?